# Change style of drop down list box

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding the following drop down to my page and I it's styled differently because of the fact that it's from an external javascript library.

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" id="countryId" value="US"/>
<select name="state" class="states order-alpha" id="stateId">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
<select name="city" class="cities order-alpha" id="cityId">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//geodata.solutions/includes/statecity.js"></script>
```

It doesn't use the standard bootstrap style (it looks pretty old school). Any way I can style this using bootstrap?

As you can tell, I'm still new to this.

Comment: You need to add the class `form-control` for bootstrap, [as mentioned in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#selects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to put a comment, so I'll post an answer.

---

**If you're not comfortable with writing your own code (yet)**

You can customize your bootstrap look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#dropdowns) and download it after.

---

**On the other hand**

You should probably look for some beginner tutorials on CSS and HTML. :)